# Which is more efficient, more code or more conditional checks?

Tags: python, list, memory

I am doing the 7th exercise on [10 Algorithms To Solve Before your Python Coding Interview](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-algorithms-to-solve-before-your-python-coding-interview-feb74fb9bc27). It is about moving the zeroes of a list to the end. I thought of writing a function that moves those zeroes to the end or start based on a boolean argument.

```py
def move_zeroes(numbers, to_start = False):
    pass
```

The idea in my mind for the move-to-end case was this.

```py
def move_zeroes(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        if i == 0:
            numbers.remove(i)
            numbers.append(i)
```

Extending this, I came across two choices.

### More code, less conditional checks

```py
def move_zeroes(numbers, to_start = False):
    if to_start:
        for i in numbers:
            if i == 0:
                numbers.remove(i)
                numbers.insert(0, i)
    else:
        for i in numbers:
            if i == 0:
                numbers.remove(i)
                numbers.append(i)
```

### Less code, more conditional checks

```py
def move_zeroes(numbers, to_start = False):
    for i in numbers:
        if i == 0:
            numbers.remove(i)
            numbers.insert(0, i) if to_start else numbers.append(i)
```

Does there exist a way between these? Can I have less code and less conditional checks? Also, how does this scale for larger lengths of lists?

As a secondary question, in case this is not possible, what is the practical way to do this particular example, keeping in mind memory and extra lines? In other words, which of the two tradeoffs is better than the other?

**EDIT 1: Rename list parameter to numbers on the suggestion of @aaossa.**

Comment: The two codes are equally performant.

Comment: Try to avoid using variable names that match class types. That means, do nor name your list `list`. This could have unintended effects if you try to create a list inside one of your functions using `list(something)`

Comment: As @luk2302 said, both codes have equal performance in Python. This means that the more readable code is the best.

Comment: @luk2302 Do you mean because the better performance of the first one is insignificant?

Comment: Going with what others said, long lines in python are not preferred. So in my opinion the first one is more readable.

Comment: Do neither. Functions are first-class objects: set `f` to an appropriate function *before* the loop, then call `f(i)` unconditionally inside the loop.

Comment: Note that calling `list.remove` while iterating over `list` is going to cause problems.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears to be wrong only for one of the two cases.

Comment: @chepner What would you make `f` when `to_start` is true?

Comment: So does the equal performance mean that Python does not run the if else repeatedly, which is not contributing to the running time?

Comment: That's for the OP to decide. How you fix the iteration issue will affect how you refactor the code, though.

Comment: @chepner With `lambda i: list.insert(0, i)`, it does become noticeably slower in my tests.

Comment: The article keeps talking about "solving" *algorithms* (even in the title). Gives me very little faith in the author.

Answer (score 0):

Continually calling *remove()* (notwithstanding the fact that you shouldn't do that on a list that you're currently iterating over) could be very inefficient as the list has to be scanned from its first element until such time as the remove criterion has been matched.

I propose this:

```
alist = [1,0,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5]

def move_zeroes(lst):
    # build a list from all the non-zero elements of the input list
    newlist = list(filter(None, lst))
    # the difference in the lengths of the original and new list
    # will be the number of zeroes that were not copied
    nz = len(lst) - len(newlist)
    # now extend the new list with a list of zeroes of appropriate
    # length and copy into the address space of the given parameter
    lst[:] = newlist + [0] * nz

move_zeroes(alist)

print(alist)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
temp = 0
for i in range(len(list2)):
    for k in range(i+1, len(list2)):
        if list2[i] == 0 and list2[i] < list2[k]:
            temp = list2[i]
            list2[i] = list2[k]
            list2[k] = temp
```

print(list2)

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] your answer will be like this and you won't need any use of an in-built function and can still easily convert the code into a function

Comment: Please [edit] to update your answer instead of commenting.

Comment: Whilst this is functionally correct it's very inefficient. With that dataset you need 45 comparisons. Consider what happens with larger datasets and bear in mind that the original question is about efficiency

Comment: thank you very much I will work on the solution you gave, thanks